# run a looping command in 10 terminals

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

an easy question from some of you.

I need to run a command which take into account 10 different files. For some reasons I need to run this command for each file in parallel possibly in 10 different terminals.

Is there a way to do this in a shell script? Ideally, I would open terminals in a loop i=10  then loopin into the files folder, however I do not know hot to open different terminals in a loop and assign a command to each one.

I hope it is clear, if not let me know

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to solve your problem, but if for some reason just want to open 10 terminals and in "parallel" run a command within them, you could give a try to `tmux` with the option `synchronize-panes on`, you could use this script for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in {1..10}
do
    tmux split-window
    tmux select-layout tiled
done

clear

tmux select-layout tiled

tmux setw synchronize-panes on
```

After having `tmux` running  just run it, it should look than something like the attached picture:

[image]